# multiple Filtering based on date in R by Quarters,

Tags: r

Below is a dataset where I would like to retrieve all data that comes under Quarter 1,2,3,4 and for that particular year. Say for example if the year is 2013 and I want a report for 4th quarter of 2013. can anyone help me on this.

```
ID    Phase     Date       Result   

1001   2     20/09/2013   complete

1003   3     20/01/2014   END

1002   1     20/06/2013   complete

1004   2     02/03/2013   Initiated

1004   2     02/12/2013   Initiated
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `quarter` from `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)
QQ <- read.table(
  header=TRUE, text='
ID  Phase   Date    Result
1001    2   20/09/2013  complete
1003    3   20/01/2014  END
1002    1   20/06/2013  complete
1004    2   2/3/2013    Initiated
1004    2   2/12/2013   Initiated')
QQ$Date <- as.Date(QQ$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
QQ[quarter(QQ$Date) == 4, ]
#    ID Phase       Date    Result
#5 1004     2 2013-12-02 Initiated

quarter(QQ$Date)
#[1] 3 1 2 1 4
```

Comment: I agree that this is a closer fit to SO than here. But the norm for questions there is that you show code that is problematic, not just ask for code.